# How to read value of QLineEdit value from another Python file when Push Button is clicked

Tags: python, pyqt5

Am trying to read the value of a QLineEdit (search_dir_te in prog) from another python file when push button is clicked. But it is failing. Please guide.

**First.py:**

```
class Display(QWidget): 

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        search_dir_label = QLabel('Directory to Search')
        self.search_dir_te = QLineEdit()
        search_dir_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        search_dir_layout.addWidget(search_dir_label)
        search_dir_layout.addWidget(self.search_dir_te)
        vert_layout1.addLayout(search_dir_layout)

        search_button = QPushButton('Search')
        search_button.clicked.connect(initiatesearch)   
        cancel_button = QPushButton('Cancel')
        search_cancel_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        search_cancel_layout.addWidget(search_button)
        search_cancel_layout.addWidget(cancel_button)
        search_cancel_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        vert_layout1.addLayout(search_cancel_layout)
```

---

**Second.py**

```
    def initiatesearch(self):
        print(self.search_dir_te.text())
```

I have imported initiatesearch function in First.py

Answer (score 0):

You are unnecessarily intertwining the parts of your application, and that is a sign of a bad design. A function is like a black box: Receive information, process it and return results. In this case "initiatesearch" you should only get the text and not the widget or other elements:

```py
def initiatesearch(text):
    print(text)
```

```py
class Display(QWidget): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        search_dir_label = QLabel('Directory to Search')
        self.search_dir_te = QLineEdit()
        search_dir_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        search_dir_layout.addWidget(search_dir_label)
        search_dir_layout.addWidget(self.search_dir_te)
        vert_layout1.addLayout(search_dir_layout)

        search_button = QPushButton('Search')
        search_button.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)   
        cancel_button = QPushButton('Cancel')
        search_cancel_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        search_cancel_layout.addWidget(search_button)
        search_cancel_layout.addWidget(cancel_button)
        search_cancel_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        vert_layout1.addLayout(search_cancel_layout)

    def onClicked(self):
        initiatesearch(self.search_dir_te.text())
```

**Update:**

If you still want to do knowing that it is a bad practice then you can do the following:

```py
def onClicked(self):
    initiatesearch(self)
```

```py
def initiatesearch(ui):
    print(ui.search_dir_te.text())
```

**Update2:**

```
from functools import partial
# ...
search_button.clicked.connect(partial(initiatesearch, self))
```

Comment: But technically is there any way to read  the values from another python file?

Comment: I got it, but is there a way and how to do it? Just want to know that.

Comment: I do not want an intermediate function (onClicked in your example). I want to pass the control directly to another file.

Comment: @surajsabat If my answer helps you then do not forget to mark as correct, if you do not know how to do it then review the [tour]