# How to get a return value from a connect function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to get the return value of the checkFinish Function, the purpose is to do 'something' if the value I get is False, is there a way to get the return value of a function started by the connect function? (asking about the button at the same time because it's probably the same way.)

code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from functools import partial

registered = False
loginClick = False

def login():
    global loginClick
    loginClick = True


def checkFinish():
    global registered, loginClick
    if loginClick or registered:
        return False
    else: 
        return True


def register_form():
    global registered, loginClick
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    dlg = uic.loadUi("registerForm.ui")
    dlg.usernameLine.setFocus()
    dlg.logInButton.clicked.connect(login)
    dlg.timer = QTimer(dlg, interval=5)
    dlg.timer.timeout.connect(checkFinish) # Get the return value from here.
    #if dlg.timer.timeout.connect(checkFinish): do something example
    dlg.timer.start()
    dlg.show()
    app.exec()
```

Let's say I click the logInButton, the login function will change the value of loginClick to True and the Function checkFinish that runs in the background because of the timer will return False, the problem again is how to get that False value in the register_form function where I start the timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signal only serves to invoke a function and pass it some parameters so you cannot get the result of the function invoked. The correct logic is to invoke another function that evaluates the initial function:

```
# ...
dlg.timer = QTimer(dlg, interval=5)
def onTimeout():
    if checkFinish():
        print("finish")
dlg.timer.timeout.connect(onTimeout)
dlg.timer.start()
# ...
```

Comment: I need to return a value from the function register_form, and that's why I wanted to get the returned value and not only activate a function, I need some kind of condition so I can return True or False from register_form, and the point was that if checkFinish returns False I will also return false/True in the register_form.
if I get in return False I am supposed to close the window and return False to the file i opened it from ( the file where I imported the register_form function and used it to show the register window not shown in the code above just to try and say what i am trying to do.)

Comment: @Matan I think you have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and it seems to me that it is the cause of a bad design, today I also answered a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60344095/6622587) and I think the user must be your group (or maybe that user is you with another account). If so, I recommend rethinking your logic as you will have more headaches